# Selenium webdriver import issues

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

While this likely comes back to an incomplete understanding of Python's Import behaviour, I was hoping someone could explain why the following happens within the context of Selenium.

If I try `from selenium import *`, then I get `NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined`.

If I use `from selenium import webdriver`, then everything works.

Why is this?

Comment: @ozgur Version 2.53.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the top level `__init__.py` file of the selenium project, you'll see:

```
from selenium import selenium
```

so it importing selenium actually imports the `selenium.py` file which doesn't have any class, variable etc. named `webdriver` in it.

Here is the module hierarchy of selenium 2.53.6:

```
selenium
 -- __init__.py
 -- selenium.py
 -- webdriver
    -- ...
```

To actually import `webdriver` module, you should do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: So is there any way to import everything from Selenium? My list is increasing, including webdriver, Alerts, Keys, and now exceptions. It's getting a bit tedious.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with selenium. Where do you import alerts, keys and exceptions?

Comment: "from selenium import webdriver", "from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert", "from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys", "from selenium.common.exceptions import *"

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You need to import explicitly if you want to use them. Btw, wildcard imports might cause namespace collisions so it's always a better practice to import only what you want to use.